# Getting error while updating user information in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating an simple website where a user can create a account, login into their account and update his/her information.

I was able to do the first two part ( creating account and login ) but I am stuck at updating part.

I have created a User Schema

**/modules/User.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const md5 = require('md5');
const validator = require('validator');
const mongodbErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-errors');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please Enter a username',
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Address'],
        required: 'Please Enter an Email Address',
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please Enter your Name',
    },
});

userSchema.virtual('gravatar').get(function () {
    const hash = md5(this.email);
    return `https://gravatar.com/avatar/${hash}`;
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'username' });
userSchema.plugin(mongodbErrorHandler);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Then I created the routes.

**/routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers');


router.get('/login', userController.loginForm);
router.post('/login', authController.login);

router.get('/register', userController.registerForm);
router.post(
    '/register',
    userController.validateRegister,
    userController.register,
    authController.login
);

router.get('/logout', authController.logout);

router.get('/account', authController.isLoggedIn, userController.account);
router.post('/account', catchErrors(userController.updateAccount));

module.exports = router;
```

Then I created the authController (where I handel the actual login and logout) and userController

**/controllers/authController.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');

exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
    successRedirect: '/',
    successFlash: 'You are now logged in!',
});

exports.logout = (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', 'You are now logged out!');
    res.redirect('/login');
};

exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
};
```

> I have created the passport strategy in an another folder

**/controllers/userControllers.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
};

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', { title: 'Register' });
};

exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
    req.sanitizeBody('name');
    req.sanitizeBody('username');
    req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('username', 'You must enter a unique username!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not Valid!').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
        remove_dots: false,
        remove_extension: false,
        gmail_remove_subaddress: false,
    });
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody(
        'confirm-password',
        'Confirm-Password Cannot be Blank!'
    ).notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('confirm-password', "Oops! Password Didn't matched!").equals(
        req.body.password
    );

    const errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        req.flash(
            'error',
            errors.map((err) => err.msg)
        );
        res.render('register', {
            tite: 'Register',
            body: req.body,
            flashes: req.flash(),
        });
        return;
    }
    next();
};

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
    });
    const register = promisify(User.register, User);
    await register(user, req.body.password);
    // res.send('it works!!');
    next();
    // res.render('register', { title: 'Register' });
};

exports.account = (req, res) => {
    res.render('account', { title: 'Your Account' });
};

exports.updateAccount = async (req, res) => {
    const updates = {
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
    };

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $set: updates },
        { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
    );

    req.flash('success', 'Updated');
    res.redirect('back');
};
```

In `userController.js` I have created a controller **validateRegister** which will validate the registration and check if the username and email is unique and check if both the password is same or not. If every think is fine then it will register the user, and if any thing goes wrong it will flash error.

For updating the user account I have created a controller **updateAccount**. Here I first select the fields which I have to update and find that particular user by using `findOneAndUpdate` method and pass the the query, updates and options.

Everything works fine till here. If I try to update the name it will work, if i try to update the username or emailId which is unique then also it will work fine.

But the problems arise when I try to update my username or emailId which is not unique or take by another user.

Then it is showing this error.

```
Cannot read property '1' of null

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at model.Query.mongodbErrorHandler (\node_modules\mongoose-mongodb-errors\lib\plugin.js:19:49)
```

In options I also mentioned that to run the validators `{ new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }` but instead of mentioning, it is working.

When someone try to update his/her username or emailId to a username or emailId which is already taken by an another user it should show the flashes which I have passed in the **validateRegister**

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. I this I am making mistake somewhere in **updateAccount** controller but I am not able to figure it out.

Please help me.

Thanks for Reading!